# In Android how Detach app from the one invoked it through intent?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I launched my application after clicking the link on the whats-app with concept of deep-linking. after that i press the home, and every time when i launched the application whats-app and it opens my application. it looks like application remains attached. any help to solve this problem?

Comment: Just press back on mobile when in you application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can find the official guidelines how to launch "UP" in your own app stack: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

you have to define your "home" activity in the manifest like this:

```
<activity
   android:name=".DeepLinkActivity"
   android:parentActivityName="com.my.app.HomeActivity">
```

then on pressing UP you process this code:

```
Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
   // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
   // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
   TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
   // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
       .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
       // Navigate up to the closest parent
       .startActivities();
} else {
   // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
   // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
   NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
}
```